# can you use rollmedian with even length k?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called mydata and I'd like to add a rolling median for lags 2 to 9.  Currently I am using rollmedianr with the code below:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(TTR)
date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-01-10"),"day")
value =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
mydata = data.frame (date, value)
mydata
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('MED',2:9) := lapply(2:9, function(x) rollmedianr(value, x, fill = rep(NA,x-1)) ),][]

         date value MED2 MED3 MED4 MED5 MED6 MED7 MED8 MED9
 1: 2016-01-01     1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 2: 2016-01-02     2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 3: 2016-01-03     3    3    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 4: 2016-01-04     4    4    3    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 5: 2016-01-05     5    5    4    4    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
 6: 2016-01-06     6    6    5    5    4    4   NA   NA   NA
 7: 2016-01-07     7    7    6    6    5    5    4   NA   NA
 8: 2016-01-08     8    8    7    7    6    6    5    5   NA
 9: 2016-01-09     9    9    8    8    7    7    6    6    5
10: 2016-01-10    10    2    9    3    8    4    7    5    6
```

But in the description of the rollmedianr() function "k" must be odd so that the results are incorrect. You can see MED4 in row 4 shows "3" but that should be the median of median(c(1,2,3,4)) which is 2.5.   I would like to calculate the proper rolling median for both even and odd "k".

I thought this might work:

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('Calc',2:9) := lapply(2:9, function(x) rollapply(value,x,FUN="median",align="left"))][]
```

but it is incorrect as you can see below. "Calc2" should be  NA, 1.5,2 etc......

```
          date value Calc2 Calc3 Calc4 Calc5 Calc6 Calc7 Calc8 Calc9
 1: 2016-01-01     1   1.5     2   2.5     3   3.5     4   4.5     5
 2: 2016-01-02     2   2.5     3   3.5     4   4.5     5   5.5     6
 3: 2016-01-03     3   3.5     4   4.5     5   5.5     6   6.5     5
 4: 2016-01-04     4   4.5     5   5.5     6   6.5     7   4.5     6
 5: 2016-01-05     5   5.5     6   6.5     7   7.5     4   5.5     5
 6: 2016-01-06     6   6.5     7   7.5     8   3.5     5   6.5     6
 7: 2016-01-07     7   7.5     8   8.5     3   4.5     6   4.5     5
 8: 2016-01-08     8   8.5     9   2.5     4   5.5     7   5.5     6
 9: 2016-01-09     9   9.5     2   3.5     5   6.5     4   6.5     5
10: 2016-01-10    10   1.5     3   4.5     6   7.5     5   4.5     6
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc2' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
2: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 8 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc3' (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items).
3: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 7 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc4' (recycled leaving remainder of 3 items).
4: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 6 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc5' (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items).
5: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc7' (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items).
6: In `[.data.table`(setDT(mydata), , `:=`(paste0("Calc", 2:9), lapply(2:9,  :
  Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'Calc8' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not actually state what result is desired but maybe this is what you want.  (If you want left alignment then use `rollapply` instead of `rollapplyr` and add `align="left"` -- one can't tell since one example in the question uses right alignment and another uses left.)

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('MED',2:9) := 
                 lapply(2:9, rollapplyr, data = value, median, fill = NA),][]
```

giving:

```
          date value MED2 MED3 MED4 MED5 MED6 MED7 MED8 MED9
 1: 2016-01-01     1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 2: 2016-01-02     2  1.5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 3: 2016-01-03     3  2.5    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 4: 2016-01-04     4  3.5    3  2.5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 5: 2016-01-05     5  4.5    4  3.5    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
 6: 2016-01-06     6  5.5    5  4.5    4  3.5   NA   NA   NA
 7: 2016-01-07     7  6.5    6  5.5    5  4.5    4   NA   NA
 8: 2016-01-08     8  7.5    7  6.5    6  5.5    5  4.5   NA
 9: 2016-01-09     9  8.5    8  7.5    7  6.5    6  5.5    5
10: 2016-01-10    10  9.5    9  8.5    8  7.5    7  6.5    6
```